# Using spinner in android app

Tags: android, android-spinner

Can someone please help me. I have just started Android development and I want to create an app which has a drop down menu. There seems to be two errors in my code which I am unable to resole. The errors are at implements `OnItemSelectedListner` and at `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
        int Cups = 1;
        int Price = 1;
        int Sum = 0;
        private Spinner spinner;
        private static final String[]paths = {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        }



        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) 
            {
                case 0:
                    Price=0.5;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Price=1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Price=2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Price=3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Price=4;
                    break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post the logs of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **first** Error is to implement the correct [OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

```
implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
```

The **second** is to override the correct method from the listener which is

```
@Override
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}
```